# Zend Mail goes to spam box in gmail but outlook goes to inbox, why?

Tags: zend-mail

I got this same problem:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10200

this guy has solved it but i don't understand it.

he said: "I sent once "HELO/EHLO" and my issue solved."

anyone could tell me?